# Calculations with quotients in ring theory. Which rules are true?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ a ring and let $(a),(b)$ principal ideals. Is it true that $$R/(a,b)=\frac{R/(a)}{(b)}?$$

I'm reading a book about rings, and it seems that they are using all kind of those tricks. But I'm not sure if they are using it and if they are true. Does somebody knows some kind of list of rules (preferable with proofs) of what I can and what I can't use when I try to calculate with quotients ?

Is one of the following rules true for example ?

- $$ a (R/I) ≅ (aR)/I$$
- $$(a)/I + (b)/I ≅ (a,b)/ I $$

Comment: out of three, which do you think is always true?? (at least intuitively)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik $(a,b)/(a) ≅(b)$ must be always true it seems to me.

Comment: supppose for simplicity, let us take $I=(0)$ in third statement, will that be true then??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I think it is true in that case:
$$(a)/(0) + (b)/(0) ≅ (a) + (b) ≅ (a,b) ≅ (a,b)/ (0)$$

Comment: I am not able to give valid proof but i feel that should be true in general... let us wait for some others response...